# Does PuTTY command-line accepts multiple file arguments?

Tags: putty

I need this below command-line to accept multiple  file arguments. Is it possible?

```
putty.exe -ssh -pw password username@host -m file1 file2 -t
```

Why two files?  Because I can define and maintain all my exports in a common file, rather defining it in all command files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, PuTTY does not support that.

But you can merge the two files on the fly:

```
copy file1 + file2 %TEMP%\cmd
putty.exe -ssh -pw password username@host -m %TEMP%\cmd
```

---

And actually for automation, you should use Plink, not PuTTY.

And the Plink supports input redirection. So you can use:

```
(
    type file1
    type file2
) | plink.exe -T -ssh -pw password username@host
```

Note that the Plink is a part of the PuTTY package.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks :)